# Pod injected with istio-sidecar are not created

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have installed istio with below command.

```
istioctl install --set profile=default -y
```

And I created `istio-injection=enabled` label to specific namespace.
But, Replicaset of that namespace occur below error.

```
Warning  FailedCreate  12m (x20 over 53m)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "namespace.sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

So I used the below command in another container.

**Command**

```
curl https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject
```

**Out**

```
Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
root@general-component-b477fd4b8-qdfqn:/# curl https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
root@general-component-b477fd4b8-qdfqn:/# curl http://istiod.istio-system.svc:80/inject
curl: (7) Failed to connect to istiod.istio-system.svc port 80: Connection timed out
root@general-component-b477fd4b8-qdfqn:/# curl https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

There seems to be a problem with SSL, but I just did a basic install.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Please check if the istiod pod is running under istio-system namespace.

Comment: @NatarajMedayhal
Clearly, istiod pod are running in istio-system namepsace.

Comment: Istiod is not able to inject the sidecar during the pod creation.  You can check restarting the istiod pod.  You can check mutating web hook configuration by running kubectl get mutatingwebhookconfigurations